# How to do lazy loading for a trend chart of an angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

**Introduction:**
I'm working on an Angular application that displays time series data (x axis has timestamps) in a trend chart. The dataset contains a month's worth of data, causing performance issues when loading the chart. I'm experiencing the following browser console warnings:
Error shown in Browser Console:

```
[Violation] 'load' handler took 372ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 42ms
```

**Structure:**
In the application, there are two components **trend chart** and **report component**.
Report component is where the trend chart is displayed.

**Possible way of solving**:
Implement the trend chart to show in a way that it displays few points like one week worth of data and when the user pans to left, previous data is shown and if right then fetch new data if there's any new data. So basically panning the time stamp values.

**Problem facing**
I am uncertain about the best way to implement this. Specifically, I'm not sure whether the TrendChartComponent should handle fetching new data upon panning or if this logic should reside in the ReportsComponent.

Sample Code:
*report-component.ts* :

```
export class ReportsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('container') container!: ElementRef;
  queryParam: any;
  showDataNotFound = false;
  selectedButton: any;
  checked: boolean = false;
  monthName: Date = new Date();
  buttonsArray: { label: string | null; id: number; checked: any }[] = [];
  currentMonthID: number = 0;
  months: activemonths = {
    message: '',
    data: [
      {
        month_id: 0,
        month: new Date()
      },
    ],
  };
  lineChartLabels: Label[] = [];
  chartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [], label: 'Humidex', lineTension: 0, steppedLine: true, borderWidth: 1 },
    { data: [], label: 'Heat Index1', lineTension: 0, steppedLine: true, borderWidth: 1 },
    { data: [], label: 'Heat Index2', lineTension: 0, steppedLine: true, borderWidth: 1 },
    { data: [], label: 'Heat Index3, lineTension: 0, steppedLine: true, borderWidth: 1 }
  ];

  constructor(
    private service: Service,
    private datePipe: DatePipe,
    private exportAsService: ExportAsService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private loadingService: LoaderService
  ) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadingService.setLoading(false);
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      // console.debug(JSON.stringify(params));
      this.queryParam = params['result'];
    });
    this.service.GetActiveMonths().subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        if (response.status === 'error') {
          // console.debug(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
        else {
          const today = new Date();
          const month = (today.getMonth() + 1).toLocaleString('en-US', {
            minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
            useGrouping: false,
          });
          const year = today.getFullYear();
          this.currentMonthID = Number(year + month);
          this.months = response;
          for (const obj of this.months.data) {
            const tempDate = new Date(obj.month);
            const monthname = this.datePipe.transform(obj.month, 'MMMM');
            const monthid = obj.month_id;
          }
        }
      },
    });
  }
  getMonthReport(id: number, checked: boolean) {
    this.showDataNotFound = false; // to not show data not found
    const payload = {
      MonthID: `${id}`,
    };
    this.loadingService.setLoading(false);
    this.sgipservice.GetActiveMonthRecords(payload).subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        if (response.status === 'error') {
          this.showDataNotFound = true;
        }
        else {
          this.dataSource.data = response.message;
          if (this.dataSource.data.length === 0) {
            //to show data not found when not data returned
            this.showDataNotFound = true;
          } else {
            this.displayedColumns = Object.keys(this.dataSource.data[0]);

            this.lineChartLabels = [];
            this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => {
              // console.debug(JSON.stringify(row));
              this.chartData.forEach((d: any) => {
                d.data?.push(row[d.label]);
              });
              this.lineChartLabels.push(row['Date & Timestamp']);
            });
          }
        }
        this.loadingService.setLoading(true);
      },
    });
  }
```

*service.ts*

```
  GetActiveMonthRecords(payload: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(
      this.baseApiUrl + '/month/month-rec-details?MonthId=' + payload.MonthID
    ).pipe(
      tap(response => {
        // console.log('Output from API: month/month-rec-details?MonthId=', response);
      })
    );
  }
```

*trend-chart-component.ts*

```
export class TrendChartComponent {
  @Input() public chartData: ChartDataSets[] = [];
  @Input() public lineChartLabels: Label[] = [];


  // Define chart options
  lineChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      labels: {
        fontSize: 11,
        usePointStyle: true,
        fontColor: 'white'
      }
    },
    elements:
    {
      point:
      {
        radius: 1.2,
        hitRadius: 3,
        hoverRadius: 6,
        hoverBorderWidth: 2
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      zoom: {
        pan: { enabled: true, mode: 'x', onPan: this.onPanZoom.bind(this), onPanComplete: this.onPanZoomComplete.bind(this) },
        zoom: { enabled: true, mode: 'x', onZoom: this.onPanZoom.bind(this), onZoomComplete: this.onPanZoomComplete.bind(this) },
        chart: this.setChart.bind(this)
      },
      crossline: { enabled: true },
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          type: 'time',
          ticks: {
            maxRotation: 0,
            autoSkipPadding: 50,
            sampleSize: 100
          },
          time: {
            displayFormats: {
              millisecond: 'MMM DD hh:mm:ss.SSS a',
              second: 'MMM DD hh:mm:ss a',
              minute: 'MMM DD hh:mm a',
              hour: 'MMM DD hh a',
              day: 'MMM DD hh a',
              week: 'MMM DD a',
              month: 'YY MMM DD a',
              quarter: 'YY MMM DD',
              year: 'YY MMM DD',
            }
          },
          gridLines: { color: 'rgba(127, 140, 141, 0.2)' }
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  // Define colors of chart segments
  lineChartColors: Color[] = [
  ];

  // Set true to show legends
  lineChartLegend = true;

  // Define type of chart
  lineChartType: ChartType = 'line';

  lineChartPlugins = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  // events
  chartClicked({ event, active }: { event: MouseEvent, active: {}[] }): void {
    console.log(event, active);
  }

  chartHovered({ event, active }: { event: MouseEvent, active: {}[] }): void {
    console.log(event, active);
  }

  public chartRef: any;

  private setChart({ chart }: any): void {
    this.chartRef = chart;
    // this.updateTrendAxesAvailable();
  }

  private onPanZoom({ chart }: any): void {
  }

  private onPanZoomComplete({ chart, reset }: any): void {
  }

  public zoom(): void {
    // this.chart.ngOnChanges({});

  }
  public move(): void {

  }
}
```

**Question**:
How should I structure the lazy loading implementation for this scenario? Should the data fetching logic upon panning be placed in the TrendChartComponent or in the ReportsComponent? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do not complicate a chart, just add buttons that send filter data to the backend and this will return a dataset, buttons as in `day`, `month`, `custom range`, etc. Think about the complexity and effort required to maintain this solution if there are multiple charts and each requires this functionality!